# SNOWFLAKE - How to bind variables with DDL inside a procedure?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, prepared-statement, sql-injection, procedure, ddl

I've used binding variables on statement like INSERT or SELECT with the '?' or ':1' placeholders, but I cannot use it with instructions like CREATE ROLE because it throws an exception.

I need to bind the variable to create a procedure where I would create a role with the given name. I want to avoid CONCAT t or || for sql injection reasons.

This works

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE TEST (name VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
  query VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  query:= 'SELECT * from DUMMY name =  ?';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query USING (name);
  RETURN  'OK';
END;
 
CALL TEST('OK');
```

But this returns an exception ´syntax error line 1 at position 12 unexpected '?'. when calling the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST2 (name VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
  query VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  query:= 'CREATE ROLE ?';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query USING (name);
  RETURN  'OK';
END;
 
CALL TEST2('WRONG');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are referencing object names you need to use the IDENTIFIER keyword e.g.

```
query:= 'CREATE ROLE IDENTIFIER(?)';
```